# Read all element bindings from a Vue template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to pre-process a Vue 2 template and get a list of all of the element bindings. So if I have a file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <p>Here's a message: {{message1}}</p>
    <p>Here's an input: <input type="text" v-model="message2"></p>
</div>

<script type="application/javascript" src="vue.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            message1: "foo",
            message2: "bar"
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then somewhere (beforeMount?) I could query Vue and it would tell me the bindings are ['message1', 'message2']. Is that possible?

Comment: This isn't possible at runtime. For what purpose do you need to do this? There might be another solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the necessary columns from the database, without redundantly listing all of the field names twice (once in HTML and once in JavaScript)

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand, but on the surface it looks like you could store your information from the database in the VueJs data collection as say columns. Then loop through that using v-for. The template "reacts" to data (state) which is a mental pivot when coming from something like jQuery which (generally) starts at the DOM.

Comment: That's the reverse of what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to dynamically build my page based on the columns in the database, I'm trying to dynamically build my database query based on the attributes needed on the page.

Comment: Can't you just put your column data into a separate object like `columns: { message1: 'foo', ... }`, and render the data in your template like `{{ columns.message1 }}`, that way you know that the columns will be `Object.keys(this.columns)`.

Comment: I think querying your DB based on your client's request w/o verification (or trusting your template in this case) is a bad practice. That being said, a reflection in Vue is not something I've seen before and is pretty interesting...

Comment: @DecadeMoon Yes, definitely, but I'm trying to avoid repeatedly entering the field names (message1, in your example). And if I want to add or remove fields from my template, I don't want to worry about the application breaking because I forgot to add them to my separate object; nor do I want to inefficiently fetch columns that I'm not actually displaying.

Comment: @Aviad I'm taking care of the security implications separately by having a server-side process that cross-checks the requested fields against a blacklist of sensitive fields before querying the database.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible (at least not in a clean way).

Comment: What about storing the `data` object in another file? then reading it

Comment: @Aviad either I'm totally not understanding you, or you're totally not understanding me. I'm confused about what you mean. If you'd like to post an answer with an example that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by getting the text of the render function (by calling vm.$options.render.toString() ) and then parsing the bindings from that.

For instance, the rendering function for a simple list view looks like this:

```
function() {
  var _vm = this
  var _h = _vm.$createElement
  var _c = _vm._self._c || _h
  return _c(
    "table",
    { attrs: { border: "1", cellpadding: "5", cellspacing: "0" } },
    [
      _vm._m(0),
      _vm._l(_vm.rows, function(row) {
        return _c("tr", [
          _c(
            "td",
            [
              _c("router-link", { attrs: { to: "/detail/" + row.ID } }, [
                _vm._v(_vm._s(_vm._f("truncate")(row.TITLE, 100)))
              ])
            ],
            1
          ),
          _c("td", [_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm._f("truncate")(row.DESCRIPTION, 200)))]),
          _c("td", [_vm._v(_vm._s(row.TYPE))])
        ])
      })
    ],
    2
  )
}
```

It looks like the bindings are always contained in an _s() element, and optionally a *vm.f*() instruction when using filters.